# Mongo DB shell, remove command doesn't return cursor to explain(command)?

Tags: mongodb

While inside Mongo shell, Imagine a collection named 'sample' which has following data,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58437bd02e0a90d8318cfab1"), "a" : 1, "b" : 1}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58437bf02e0a90d8318cfab3"), "a" : 2, "b" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58437bf32e0a90d8318cfab4"), "a" : 2, "b" :2}
```

`db.sample.explain().remove({a:1})` works but
`db.sample.remove({a:1}).explain()` does not work, Why?

In the video course (University@MongoDB) it is stated that remove does not return cursor, that why `db.sample.remove({a:1}).explain()` wont works. However am not able to understand that if `remove` does not return cursor then how come the explain object in `db.sample.explain().remove({a:1})` command is able to work on the query and return the Winning plan etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure this out, let's use the fact that entering a function name into the mongo shell will print the function definition.

Starting with using `explain` before `remove`:

```
> db.sample.explain
function (verbosity) {
    return new Explainable(this, verbosity);
}
```

So `explain` returns an `Explainable`.  But what's `Explainable`?

```
> Explainable
function constructor(collection, verbosity) {
    ... code omitted
    this.find = function () { ... }
    ...
    this.remove = function () { ... }
```

So `explain` returns an object that has a definition of `remove` (and all the other explainable queries) inside of it, effectively replacing the regular `remove` command without explain in front.  From looking inside the `explain.remove` definition you can see the magic is in `ConvertToExplainCmd` which causes an `explain` command to execute instead of an actual `remove` command.

Now for `remove` first before `explain`:

```
> db.sample.remove
function (t, justOne) {
    ...
    return result;
}
```

In this case the returned `result` does not define a function called `explain` so doing `db.sample.remove({a:1}).explain()` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Logan, it's quite clear to me now :) 
Next time I'll have to look deeper into the functions.